# MemoryError from BioPython's Align.PairwiseAligner()

Tags: python, out-of-memory, bioinformatics, biopython, sequence-alignment

I'm trying to write a Python3 script that performs a global alignment of two sequences, of ~ 10 kb and 11 kb length. Both are very similar to each other. (I'm trying to find the few points where they do not match, one of which I know is close to the end of the query sequence, which is why a local alignment is not sufficient (BLASTN just crops the last 2 bases to get a better alignment score).)

I had hoped to be able to use BioPython for this, specifically the Align.PairwiseAligner. However, I'm getting a MemoryError.

**Is there a way to configure or use BioPython to use less memory (more runtime is completely fine - within reason, of course)? Or any other way to perform a global alignment of 2 sequences that I can use without having to resort to external software like Emboss Needle?**

(This is part of a larger software. I already have to ship BLAST and BioPython along. I would prefer not to have to ship yet another software, if it can be avoided.)

Here's an MVCE:

```
from Bio import Align

ref_seq = "GAAAGACCTGAAAGATCACGGTGCCTTCATTTCAACTGTGAGACATGAAGTAATTTTCCCAAATCTACAACATTAAGATATGGTGCAATAAGGACCAGATTAAAGGTCTCCTGATTTGCGGCCATGTTCCCTCCATCTCCTTTACTCCTAAACACACTCACACTCACTACTGCAAATAGTTGTCTTGTCAAGTGGGAAATGAATGCTCTTACAAGGCTCAAACTTGTGAACACATCACTGACCAGCACAGAGCTGGCTACAATAGCTCCCCAATTAAGGTGTTTTACATGCAACTGGTTCAAACCTTCCAAGTGCTAAATTAAAACAATCCTTTAAAGAAGGAAATTCTGTTTCAGAAGAGGACCTTCATACAGCATCTCTGACCAGCAACTGATGATGCTATTGAACTCAGATGCTGATTGGTTCTCCAACACGAGATTACCCAACCCAGGAGCAAGGAAATCAGTAACTTCCTCCCTATAACTTGGAATGTGGGTGGAGGGGTTCATAGTTCTCCCTGAGTGAGACTTGCCTGCTAAGCTGGCCCCTGGTCCTGTCCTGTTCTCCAGCATGGTGTGTCTGAAGCTCCCTGGAGGCTCCTGCATCCTAGCGCTGACAGTGACACTGATGGTGCTGAGCTCCCCACTGGCTTTGGCTGGGGACACCCGACGTAAGTGCACATTGCGGGTGCTGAGCTACTATGGGGTGGGGAAAATAGGGAGTTTTGTTAACATTGTGCCCAGGCCATGTCCCTTAAGAAATTGTGACGTTTTCTTCAGAGATTGCCCATCTTTATCATTGGATCCCAAATTATTTCCTCCATAAAAGGAGCTTGGGTACTTGCCCTCTTCATGAGACTTGTGTAAGGGGCCTTTGCACAAGTCATTTCTTTTCAAATCTCCACCAATAAAACCTTTGCATCACATGTCCTCAGGGTCTTTAGAGGATTTAGAAATAAGGATTCTAAAATAAATTCCCCATACAGCACTTCCCTTTATTATGTTGACTTATGTCAGACAAAAGGAGGTTCTTACTGAAAATTTTGTGGGAGTCAAGGGAATTCAAAGGGTCTCTCCTAGACGATCCAGTGTTAGGTTCCCCACAGGACCTTTGGTGTTGGCCATAGTCCTCATATGTGAGGATGGACCCAGTGGCCTCCCCATTATCTCCTTTCTTTTCTTGCTGAACTCCAATGTTTATAAGGCCTGTATCCCTGTAGCGTATGTAGGTTCTCTGACAGAAGTTATACTTAGTGCTCTTCCTTTCTTGTGGGGAAAAGTCCCTGGAACTGAAGCTGAGATTGTTAGTACTTGGAGTCACCTTACAGATACAGAGCATTTATGAGGTATTCTTTGGTGCCTAAAGAACTTAAGGCATCCTCTGAAAAACTAGCCCAGGTTCGTGTTCATTATGAATCTTTTTTAACCTTTCTGTACTTGTTTCTCTTGCATCTCCTATGTGCTCTAACTAGACATGACAGAAGAGATTTAACTAATGTATAAATTATATGAAATTCTATTTTTTAAGTCAAAAATAATCAACTATCAGAAATTTAATAATGTTCAAACTATATACTCTGTGTGGGGTTACCGAGATGATGTGAACATTGTTCACGTCTCATAGGGCTGAAAGTCAATGGGCAAGTCTTGGGAACTCATTGTCTTACTGGGGTCTTGTCCTAAATTTCCTAGGTTCACCCATCATGCCCTCAGCTTTCCTTAACTAGCCATGTCTGCTTACCTCTTCCTCCAGTTTCTATTTTTCCCCAGCTATGTTGTCATCATTTCCAGAAATCTCTAAAGCTTGCACAGAACCTTAGCACTATGCGATTCATTGAAAGAGACTTTTTTTCTCTTTTTGAGGTAGGGCCTGGCTCTGTCACCCAGTCTATAGCTCAGTGGTGTGATCGAGGCTCACTGCAACCTCTGCCACCCATGCTCAAGTGATCCTCCCTCCTCAGGCTCCAGAGTAGCTGGGAATACAGGCAGGCAACCACGCCCAGCTAATTTTTGTAATTTTGGTAGACATGAGATTTTGCCATGTTGCCCAGGCTGGTCTTAAACTGCTGGTTTCAAGCAATCCTCCTGCCTTGGCCTCCCAACATGCTAGGATTATAGATGTGAGCCACTGTGCCCAGGCAAAAAGAAATGACTCTTAATAAAAAAATTTCCTTTTTCTTAAATCACTGTTTCTTTATCTGTGAATTCTTCTTCCAACTAGAAGGAGGAGAAAAAAGAAGTTTGCCTGTATTTCTCACCAGGAGGAGAAGGGGTCTAGTGTGACATTAAAATGAAAGGGTGCTGGAGCTTGAGCCCCTTCTTGCTTTCCAGGATCCCTACAGTGATCAGTTCCCATACCCTGGTTTATTCATGTAAACCACACTTATTTTTCTCAGCAGCTACTCTTTACTGGGCTCCATTCTAGGTTCAAATCATTCTATTTGATTAAGTTAGAGAGCGTCCCTACTCTCATGGAAGTTACACAAGAGTAGAGGAGACAGACACTAACCCAATAAGCATTTAACAAAGAAGATAATGTTAGAGAGTCATAGTGCACTGAAGAAAAGACATCAGGTTTGTGAAAAAGAGAGACATGGATTCACCTACTTTAGTTCATATGTTAGGGAGCTCCACCTGAGAAAGTGACATTCAGCTGAGACAACAAAATAAGTAGACAGTCGTGAAGATCTAAGGGATGAAAGTTCCAGGGAGACCAAATGGCGGGAAAGCCCTGGTGTGGGAAACTATGTGGAGGGAGAGAAAGAAAGCTAGAGGGGCTGAAGTATAGAAAGCAACGAAATGGAGAGGCAGAAGATGAGGTAGGACACAGAGAGGAAGTCAGGAGCCTCATCATTATAGGCTCTGATGTCCACGGTAAAAAAAATTTGAATTTTATTATTTATTTACCTATTTATTTGTTTATTTATTTTATTTTATTTTGTGATGGAGTCTCTCTCTGTTGCCCAGGCTAGATGGCAGTGGCACAATCTCGGCTCACTGCAACCTCCGCCTCCTGGGTTCAAGCAATTCTCCTGCCTCAGCCTCCCAATTAGCTGGGGCCACAGGTGCATGCCACCACACCTGGCTAATTTTTTGTATTTTTAGTAGGGATAGGATTTCACCGTGTTAGCCAGGATGGTCTCGATCTCCTGACCTCGTGATCCGCCCGCCTTGGCCTCCCAAAGTGCTGGGATTATAGGCGTGAGCCACTGCACCCGGCCTATATTCAATTTTTAAAACTAATTCTAGCTACTCTGTGGGGATTGGATTGTTGGGGTTCACCAGTGGTTAGGAAGACTATTTAGGAGCACAGCAGGGAATTCTCCAGGGAAAACAAGCTTGTGGCTTCATGGAGTGCATTAGTGATAAAGACGGTGAAGAAGATAAAGTGGACAGACTCGGCATGTATTTTTGCTTAGCTTGTTAATGAATTACTGTAAAGGGGGTAGAGCTTATTCCTAAGGATTTTCTTTTGACAAATAAGTGGGTGGTAGTGTTGTTTATTGAGATAGGAAAAACTATGGGAGGAAATGATTTGAAGTGGGTGGTTTGAAATAAAAGTTTTGTTTAAATATGAGATGATTGACTGACATTTATGTGGAGCAATCAGAAGGTCAATGGCATTTAAGAGACTCATGGTGAGGCTAGGGCTTCAGGTATTTATGTTGGAGGCATCAATACGTGTAGTGTGTTAAATTCCAGGGAGTGGAAGAGGATACATAGGGAGATGGATTGTGTGGAGAAACAAGAAGAGGGCACAGGCCAGCAAAGGGGGCTGAGAAAGAGCCCAGGGATGTTGGAGAAAAACCAAGAGAACATCATGTATGTAAGTCAAGGAAAACAGATTTTTTTCAAGGAGAAGGGAGAGGCCAATTGTGGTGAGTACCACTAAGAGGAGGGGGAAGTGAGAATATGACAGAGAAGCAAGTGCTGGGATTGGTGGAGTTGATATTTGCAGTCAATGGAGTATCCAGGGAGGAAACTGGATTGGACCATTTGGAGAGCAAATAAAAGTGAGGACGAGGTTAAGGTTGACTGTTCTGTGTAGAGAGCTTCAGGGAAGGATTGTTCTCTGGGTTCAGGGAGCCAGCTGAACCTAAAGGAAAAGGCTAAAGAAGCTGAAGAGAAGGAGGAGGACCTGTGAACCAGAGATGCTCAGCCATTATTAGCAAGGAAATACAAGAGAGCCCCTGTGTGCAGTGGTGACTACTCATGCAAAATGTCACACAGCCAATATTTAACACAGCCAGGATTTCACACAGCCAATATTTATTAGTGACATAGAATATATTTGTTATTGCTCTAGGTCATGAGAATGGAGTGACAAAATGAATCCGGTCGCCATCAGTATATGCCACATAACATTTTGCAGTGACTGTGTGCCAGGCCTATGAATTTCAGTATTCAATTTCAATAATGATCCTGTTGTATCTGTGGTATTTAAAAACATATACATCTCTGTAATCTAAAATTGAGAGGTTATAAGTAAAACCCAGTATTACAAATTTAGTGCTGGAAATTGATTGCAGTTTAAATCTGAGCATATAGAAAGTCCCTTTCTTCTATGTCAGCAGATGCCTTTTGTGTGAGGTTTAGGTATACTGCATTATTAGACATAAACCAGTGTTTCTGCCCTATGTTTTCAGAATGACAATTCTTTATGAAACTAATAGAAGAACAGAAGACAATTGCAAAATCATGATGAAGATACTAATTGCTTTAGAATTAAGGAATACAAATAATGTGAGCTGCAGTTATAGGGATCAAAAAAGTTACAATGGGAATGTATTTGAGTGTTTATTATGTGATCAGTGCTAAGAAGTGTCATCATTTAATTTTACACTTAACAGTAATCCTGTGAGGATTATGCTATTATTAAATGCACTTGATACATTACAAAAAGGCTTATGGTTGATATAAATTGACCCAAGTAGAAGAGATCATGTTTTTATTCAGGTTTTCTGATTCTAGAGTTTGAGAGTTTGACCATCATTAGTGAGTAGTGACTATATTGTGTCTGAATTATTGACAGAATTTCTGATATTCATATGTACCAGGTTGTTTCTTAGAGTGGGAGCAGAGATGCAAGGGCTGCTAGTTCCGATGTGTAGGAGAAACTATCATTCATTTTGCATTTATCATTTTAAACGTTCTATATGTCTATCCTGGGCATGTGTTGAAGAACACAAGGAAGTATTAAATCACTCCTTCTTCTGAAGTTTGACTGGCAAAATTGGGCTAGAGTTACGAAATAAAATACAGGTTCCTAGTGAAATCTGAATTTCAGATACACAACCATAATTTATTGGAAATCCAAATTTAACTGGATATCTTCTATTATTCTCTGTTCTAGAACTCCACACTTCTAACATTTCTCATTCCTGTCTAAGCTCTTGTGTGTTTGGTTTTTGGCCATCGCTTTCACTGCTCTTTAAGCTCCCCCAGTAGAGTGGAGAGGTCTGTTTTCCCTCGTTTGGATTCCTACAGGCAGCGCAGGCCTGGCACAAGGTCATCACTAAGGAAGTGTTCACAGGGTGAAGGCGGTGGGTGCTGTTGAAGGAACCGGTAAAGCCTGTGGGATGAGAGAAGGAGCAGAGAGTGTTTTTGGGGTGGAGGCTCCCAGGAGGAGGCGGGACGGGCTGCGGTGCTGGGCGGATCCTCCTCCAGCTCCTGCTTGGAGGTCTCCAGAACAGGCTGGAGGCAGGGAGGGGGTCCCAAAAGCCTGGGGATGAGAAGGGGTTTTCCCGCATGGTCCCCCAGGCCCCCGTTCGCCTCAGGAAGACGGAGGATGAGCTCCTGGGCTGCTGGTGGTGGGCGTTGCGGGTGGGGCCGGTTAAGGTTCCCAGTGCCCGCACCCTGCCCAGGGAGCCCCGGATGGTGGCGTCGCTGTCAGTGTCTTCTCAGGAGGCTGCCCGTGTGACCGGATCCTTCGTGTCCCCACAGCACGTTTCTTGTGGCAGCTTAAGTTTGAATGTCATTTCTTCAATGGGACGGAGCGGGTGCGGTTGCTGGAAAGATGCATCTATAACCAAGAGGAGTCCGTGCGCTTCGACAGCGACGTGGGGGAGTACCGGGCGGTGACGGAGCTGGGGCGGCCTGATGCCGAGTACTGGAACAGCCAGAAGGACCTCCTGGAGCAGAGGCGGGCCGCGGTGGACACCTACTGCAGACACAACTACGGGGTTGGTGAGAGCTTCACAGTGCAGCGGCGAGGTGAGCGCGGCGCGGGGCGGGGCCTGAGTCCCTGTAAGCGGAGAATCTGAGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTAAGAAAGAGAGAGAGCGCGCCATCTGTGAGCATTTAGAATCCTCTCAATCCCCAGCAAGCAGTTCTGAGAGCACAGGTGTGTGTGTAGAGTGTGGATTTGTCTGGGTATGTCTGTTGTGGGAGGGGAGGCAGGAGGGGGCTGATTCTTATCCTTGGAGACCTCTGTGGGGAGGTGACAAGGGAGGTGGGTGCTGGGGGCTGGAGAGAGAGGAGACCTTGATTGTCTCGGGTCCTTAGAGATGCGGGGAAGGGAAATGTAAGGGGTGTGTGATTGGGGTGAAGGTTTAGGGGAGGACTGCTGAGGGGTAAGGAAGGTTTGGGATAATGTGAGGAGGCCGGTTCCAGACTCTCCCTGGCATACACCCTTCGTGTAATCTCTGAAATAAAAGTGTGTGCTGTTTGTTTGTAAAAGCATTAGATTAATTTCTAGAGGAACTGAGTAGACCTCTGAGGCACTCCTGAAGCTTCTTTATATCTAAATTTCTTGCTAGTTTTTTGGGTTTTTTTAGTGTGTATATTTTTACATAGTAGAAATGACTGTGAAACTAACTTTTTGAATTAAAGTTTTAACACAGTTACTATTTTATTATAATGCTAGTTTTCTAGTAGTTACATATTATTCTTTTATATATAATAGTTATGACACAACTCACCTCACTTTCCCCTTTGTTGACCTTTATTATGACATTCACCAAAAGTTGAAAATGTATGTTTCTGGTTAATTTTTAATTTATATTTTTTATTTGTAATTGCTTTGAATTATTTTGACCTATTTATTGGCGGATTATAATTATTGCTCTAAGAATTCCCTATTGTATTTGGTAGGCAATGGACAATGATCTATGGTCTGATATCTTGAGGGCTTAGTATTTTTCTCAGTGACTTTGTGGGTTCTTTGTGCTATAAGATTATTAACACTTTATTGATATTTGATCCAGCATTTGCTTCAGTTTGTGGTTTGTATGTGGATTTTGAAAGTTCTTTTCCATGTTAAGAATTTGAACTTTTTATTTAATAAAATATATTGCAAAATTTTTATTAATGATTTACAATCCATCTTAAATCTGCCATTTTGTGGCATTGTTGTCTCCAGGTTCCTCCTTACTTCTAAAAAAAATAGTTGTATTTATTGAGAGTATGCTAGTGTTGGGGATTTTCCTGGGCATAAGCACCCCAAGTAACAAGTCCCAGACACTGCCTTAATCCAAATGTGACTCTGGAAAGAAAAATCATTTTACAATGATAGGCCTAATAATAATTATGCTTGTGTTACACGGGAGATGCATTGATCAGCTAAATGTAAATATAAGAACTTTCAAAACTAAAATGACATTCCCTAATCCTTTTCTCTGCTTCGGGACTCATGCTTTTCTAGGAACGTAAAAATTTGGAGAATCATTTCTGTCTGTCCCACATTCCCAGGGGCAGAACAATTTCTGTTTTGTTCTAAGGTGTGAGTGCATGGCAGTAGTATTCCTAAAATTCATACTCGGTTTCCTCATGTACCCAATTCTGTCCCTTTATCTATGCATATTTCTTTAAATCATATTTTTCTGTCATGGGGTACAAGGATGATAAATAGGTGCCAAGTGGAGCACCCAAGTGTGATGAGCGCCCTCACAGTGGAATGGAGTGAGAAGCTTTCTGACCTTATAAACTGAAGGCTATCTTCAGTCATTGTTTTATATATTTTACATGCATTAATCCTCATATAACCCCAAGAGGTAAATTAGTATAATTATCCTTCATTGTAGGTGACAAAGTTGAGACACAGAAGAATCAAAAAACTCTTCCAGGATCAACCAGTAAAAGGCAGACCTTGGATTCGAACCAAGCAACCTGGCTCAAATATCAGTTTTAATTACTACACTCTATACTTTCCAAGATTTGTAAACAGTTTGACAATGCATGCCAATTTAAAGCTATGAAGAAACAAACACAATTTTTCACAACACCTCTCAAATCTAATGGGTCCTCACTGTCAAGATTAAATTCCAGGCTGATGACACTGTAAGGTCACATGGCCAGCTGTGCTATAGGCCTGGTCAAGGTCAGAGCCTGGGTTTGCAGAGAAGCAGACACACAGCCAAACCAGGAGACTTACTCTGTCTTCCTGACTCATTCTCTCTACATTTGTTTTCTCCTAGTTGAGCCTAAGGTGACTGTGTATCCTTCAAAGACCCAGCCCCTGCAGCACCACAACCTCCTGGTCTGCTCTGTGAGTGGTTTCTATCCAGGCAGCATTGAAGTCAGGTGGTTCCGGAACGGCCAGGAAGAGAAGGCTGGGGTGGTGTCCACAGGCCTGATCCAGAATGGAGATTGGACCTTCCAGACCCTGGTGATGCTGGAAACAGTTCCTCGGAGTGGAGAGGTTTACACCTGCCAAGTGGAGCACCCAAGTGTGACGAGCCCTCTCACAGTGGAATGGAGTGAGCAGCTTTCTGACTTCATAAATTTCTCACCCACCAAGAAGGGGACTGTGCTAATCCCTGAGTGTCAGGTTTCTCCTCTCCCACACCCTATTTTCATTTGCTCCATGTTCTCATCTCCATCAGCACAGGTCACTGGGGGTAGCCCTGTAGGTGTTTCTAGAAACACCTGTACCTCCTGGAGAAGCAGTCTCACCTGCCAGGCAGGAGAGACTGTCCCTCTTTTGAACCTCCCCATGATTTCGCAGGTCAGGGTCACCCACTCTCCCCAGGCTCCAGGCCCTGCTTCTGGGTCTGAGACTGAGTTTCTGGTGCTGTTGCTCTGAGTTATTTTTTGTGATCTGGGAAGAGGAGAAGTGTAGGGGCCTACCTGACATGAGGGGAATCCAATCTCAGCCCTGCCTTTTATTAGCTCTGTCACTCTAGACAAACTACTTAGCTTCATTGAGTCTCAGGCTTTCTGTTGATCAGATGTTGAACGCTTGCCTTACATCAAGGCTGTAATATTTGAATGAGTTTGATGTCTGAACATCGTAACTGTTCAGCGTGATTTGAAATCCTTTTTTTCTCCTGAAATGGCTAGTTATTTTAATTCTTGTGGGGCAGGCTTCTGCCCCATTTTCAAAGCTCTGAATCTTAGAGTCTCAATTAAAGAGGTTCAATTTGGAATAAGCATCACTAAACCTGGATTCCTCTCTCAGGAGCACGGTCTGAATCTGCACAGAGCAAGATGCTGAGTGGAGTCGGGGGCTTCGTGCTGGGCCTGCTCTTCCTTGGGGCCGGGCTGTTCATCTACTTCAGGAATCAGAAAGGTGAGGAGCCTTTGGGAGCTGACTCTCTCCATAGGCTTTTCTGGAGGAGGAACCATGGTTTTGCTGAGAGGTTAGTTCTCAGTATACGAGTGGCCCTGAATAAAGCCTTTCTTTCCCCAAACGGCTCTAATGTCCTGCTAATCCAGAAATCATCAGTGCATGGTTACTATGTCAAAGCATAATAGCTTGTGGCCTGCAGAGACAAGAGGAAGGTTAACAAGTAGGGGTCCTTTTGTTTGAGATCCTGGAGCAAATTAAGGAAGAGCCACTAAGGCTAATGGAATTACACTGGATCCTGTGACAGACACTTCAGGCTTCATGGGTCACATGGTCTGTCTCTGCTCCTTTCTGCCCCTTTCTGCCCTGGTTGGTGCGGGTTGTGGTGTTAGAGAAATCTCAGGTGGGAGATCTGCGGCTGGGACATTGTGTTGGAGGACAGATTTGCTTCAATAACTTTTAAGTGTATTTCTTTTCCTCTTTTTCCCAGGACACTCTGGACTTCAGCCAACAGGTAATACCTTTTAATCCTCTTTTAGAAACAGACACAGTTTCCCTAGTGAGAGGTGAAGCCAGCTGGACTTCTGGGTGGGGTGGGGACTTGGAGAACTTTTCTTACAAGAGGTTTCTAAATGCCCCAATCAGTGCTTTGTAAAAACACACCAATAGGTTCTCTGTGGCTAGCTGGATGTTTGTAAAATGGACCAATTTGCACTCTGTAAAATGGACCAATCAGCATTCTTTAAAATGGACCAATCAGCACTTTTAAAATGGGCCAATCAGCACTCTTTAAAATGGACCAATCAGCACTCTTTAAAATGGACCAATCTGCAGGACATGGGCAGGGACAAATACAGGAATAAAAGCTGGCCACCCCAACCAGCAGTGGCAACCCACTCAGGTCCTCTTCCCTGCTGTGGAAGTTTTGTTCTTTTGATCTTCACAATAAATCTTGCTGCTGCCTACTCTTTGGGTCCCTGCCGCCTTTAAGAGCTGTAACACTCACTGTGAAGGTCTGCTTGAAGTCAGCGAGACCACAAACCCACTGGAAGGAACAAACTGCGGACACACTAGAATGATGGTAGAGGTGATAAGGCATGAGACAGAAATAATAGGAAAGACTTTGGATCCAAATTTCTGATCAGGCAATTTACACCAAAATTCCTCCTCTCCACTTAGAAAAGGGCTGTGCTCTGCGGGACTATTGGCTCAGGGGAGACTCAGGAACTTGTTTTTCTGCTTCCTGCAGTGCTCTCATCTGAGCCCTTGAAAGAGGAGAAAAGAAACTGTTAGTAGAGCCAGGTTGAAAACAACACTCTCCTCTGTCTTTTGCAGGATTCCTGAGCTGAAATGCAGATGACCACATTCAAGGAAGAACCTTCTGTCCCAGCTTTGCAGAATGAAAAGCTTTCCTGCTTGGCAGTTATTCTTCCACAAGAGAGGGCTTTCTCAGGACCTGGTTGCTACTGGTTCGGCAACTGCAGAAAATGTCCTCCCTTGTGGCTTCCTCAGCTCCTGCCCTTGGCCTGAAGTCCCAGCATTGATGACAGCGCCTCATCTTCAACTTTT"
query_seq = "GAGTGAGACTTGCCTGCTAAGCTGGCCCCTGCTCCTGTCCTGTTCTCCAGCATGGTGTGTCTGAAGCTCCCTGGAGGCTCCTGCATCCTAGCGCTGACAGTGACACTGATGGTGCTGAGCTCCCCACTGGCTTTGGCTGGGGACACCCGACGTAAGTGCACATTGCGGGTGCTGAGCTACTATGGGGTGGGGAAAATAGGGAGTTTTGTTAACATTGTGCCCAGGCCATGTCCCTTAAGAAATTGTGACGTTTTCTTCAGAGATTGCCCATCTTTATCATTGGATCCCAAATTATTTCCTCCATAAAAGGAGCTTGGGTACTTGCCCTCTTCATGAGACTTGTGTAAGGGGCCTTTGCACAAGTCATTTCTTTTCAAATCTCCACCAATAAAACCTTTGCATCACATGTCCTCAGGGTCTTTAGAGGATTTAGAAATAAGGATTCTAAAATAAATTCCCCATACAGCACTTCCCTTTATTATGTTGACTTATGTCAGACAAAAGGAGGTTCTTACTGAAAATTTTGTGGGAGTCAAGGGAATTCAAAGGGTCTCTCCTAGACGATCCAGTGTTAGGTTCCCCACAGGACCTTTGGTGTTGGCCATAGTCCTCATATGTGAGGATGGACCCAGTGGCCTCCCCATTATCTCCTTTCTTTTCTTGCTGAACTCCAATGTTTATAAGGCCTGTATCCCTGTAGCGTATGTAGGTTCTCTGACAGAAGTTATACTTAGTGCTCTTCCTTTCTTGTGGGGAAAAGTCCCTGGAACTGAAGCTGAGATTGTTAGTACTTGGAGTCACCTTACAGATACAGAGCATTTATGAGGTATTCTTTGGTGCCTAAAGAACTTAAGGCATCCTCTGAAAAACTAGCCCAGGTTCGTGTTCATTATGAATCTTTTTTAACCTTTCTGTACTTGTTTCTCTTGCATCTCCTATGTGCTCTAACTAGACATGACAGAAGAGATTTAACTAATGTATAAATTATATGAAATTCTATTTTTTAAGTCAAAAATAATCAACTATCAGAAATTTAATAATGTTCAAACTATATACTCTGTGTGGGGTTACCGAGATGATGTGAACATTGTTCACGTCTCATAGGGCTGAAAGTCAATGGGCAAGTCTTGGGAACTCATTGTCTTACTGGGGTCTTGTCCTAAATTTCCTAGGTTCACCCATCATGCCCTCAGCTTTCCTTAACTAGCCATGTCTGCTTACCTCTTCCTCCAGTTTCTATTTTTCCCCAGCTATGTTGTCATCATTTCCAGAAATCTCTAAAGCTTGCACAGAACCTTAGCACTATGCGATTCATTGAAAGAGACTTTTTTTCTCTTTTTGAGGTAGGGCCTGGCTCTGTCACCCAGTCTATAGCTCAGTGGTGTGATCGAGGCTCACTGCAACCTCTGCCACCCATGCTCAAGTGATCCTCCCTCCTCAGGCTCCAGAGTAGCTGGGAATACAGGCAGGCAACCACGCCCAGCTAATTTTTGTAATTTTGGTAGACATGAGATTTTGCCATGTTGCCCAGGCTGGTCTTAAACTGCTGGTTTCAAGCAATCCTCCTGCCTTGGCCTCCCAACATGCTAGGATTATAGATGTGAGCCACTGTGCCCAGGCAAAAAGAAATGACTCTTAATAAAAAAATTTCCTTTTTCTTAAATCACTGTTTCTTTATCTGTGAATTCTTCTTCCAACTAGAAGGAGGAGAAAAAAGAAGTTTGCCTGTATTTCTCACCAGGAGGAGAAGGGGTCTAGTGTGACATTAAAATGAAAGGGTGCTGGAGCTTGAGCCCCTTCTTGCTTTCCAGGATCCCTACAGTGATCAGTTCCCATACCCTGGTTTATTCATGTAAACCACACTTATTTTTCTCAGCAGCTACTCTTTACTGGGCTCCATTCTAGGTTCAAATCATTCTATTTGATTAAGTTAGAGAGCGTCCCTACTCTCATGGAAGTTACACAAGAGTAGAGGAGACAGACACTAACCCAATAAGCATTTAACAAAGAAGATAATGTTAGAGAGTCATAGTGCACTGAAGAAAAGACATCAGGTTTGTGAAAAAGAGAGACATGGATTCACCTACTTTAGTTCATATGTTAGGGAGCTCCACCTGAGAAAGTGACATTCAGCTGAGACAACAAAATAAGTAGACAGTCGTGAAGATCTAAGGGATGAAAGTTCCAGGGAGACCAAATGGCGGGAAAGCCCTGGTGTGGGAAACTATGTGGAGGGAGAGAAAGAAAGCTAGAGGGGCTGAAGTATAGAAAGCAACGAAATGGAGAGGCAGAAGATGAGGTAGGACACAGAGAGGAAGTCAGGAGCCTCATCATTATAGGCTCTGATGTCCACGGTAAAAAAAATTTGAATTTTATTATTTATTTACCTATTTATTTGTTTATTTATTTTATTTTATTTTGTGATGGAGTCTCTCTCTGTTGCCCAGGCTAGATGGCAGTGGCACAATCTCGGCTCACTGCAACCTCCGCCTCCTGGGTTCAAGCAATTCTCCTGCCTCAGCCTCCCAATTAGCTGGGGCCACAGGTGCATGCCACCACACCTGGCTAATTTTTTGTATTTTTAGTAGGGATAGGATTTCACCGTGTTAGCCAGGATGGTCTCGATCTCCTGACCTCGTGATCCGCCCGCCTTGGCCTCCCAAAGTGCTGGGATTATAGGCGTGAGCCACTGCACCCGGCCTATATTCAATTTTTAAAACTAATTCTAGCTACTCTGTGGGGATTGGATTGTTGGGGTTCACCAGTGGTTAGGAAGACTATTTAGGAGCACAGCAGGGAATTCTCCAGGGAAAACAAGCTTGTGGCTTCATGGAGTGCATTAGTGATAAAGACGGTGAAGAAGATAAAGTGGACAGACTCGGCATGTATTTTTGCTTAGCTTGTTAATGAATTACTGTAAAGGGGGTAGAGCTTATTCCTAAGGATTTTCTTTTGACAAATAAGTGGGTGGTAGTGTTGTTTATTGAGATAGGAAAAACTATGGGAGGAAATGATTTGAAGTGGGTGGTTTGAAATAAAAGTTTTGTTTAAATATGAGATGATTGACTGACATTTATGTGGAGCAATCAGAAGGTCAATGGCATTTAAGAGACTCATGGTGAGGCTAGGGCTTCAGGTATTTATGTTGGAGGCATCAATACGTGTAGTGTGTTAAATTCCAGGGAGTGGAAGAGGATACATAGGGAGATGGATTGTGTGGAGAAACAAGAAGAGGGCACAGGCCAGCAAAGGGGGCTGAGAAAGAGCCCAGGGATGTTGGAGAAAAACCAAGAGAACATCATGTATGTAAGTCAAGGAAAACAGATTTTTTTCAAGGAGAAGGGAGAGGCCAATTGTGGTGAGTACCACTAAGAGGAGGGGGAAGTGAGAATATGACAGAGAAGCAAGTGCTGGGATTGGTGGAGTTGATATTTGCAGTCAATGGAGTATCCAGGGAGGAAACTGGATTGGACCATTTGGAGAGCAAATAAAAGTGAGGACGAGGTTAAGGTTGACTGTTCTGTGTAGAGAGCTTCAGGGAAGGATTGTTCTCTGGGTTCAGGGAGCCAGCTGAACCTAAAGGAAAAGGCTAAAGAAGCTGAAGAGAAGGAGGAGGACCTGTGAACCAGAGATGCTCAGCCATTATTAGCAAGGAAATACAAGAGAGCCCCTGTGTGCAGTGGTGACTACTCATGCAAAATGTCACACAGCCAATATTTAACACAGCCAGGATTTCACACAGCCAATATTTATTAGTGACATAGAATATATTTGTTATTGCTCTAGGTCATGAGAATGGAGTGACAAAATGAATCCGGTCGCCATCAGTATATGCCACATAACATTTTGCAGTGACTGTGTGCCAGGCCTATGAATTTCAGTATTCAATTTCAATAATGATCCTGTTGTATCTGTGGTATTTAAAAACATATACATCTCTGTAATCTAAAATTGAGAGGTTATAAGTAAAACCCAGTATTACAAATTTAGTGCTGGAAATTGATTGCAGTTTAAATCTGAGCATATAGAAAGTCCCTTTCTTCTATGTCAGCAGATGCCTTTTGTGTGAGGTTTAGGTATACTGCATTATTAGACATAAACCAGTGTTTCTGCCCTATGTTTTCAGAATGACAATTCTTTATGAAACTAATAGAAGAACAGAAGACAATTGCAAAATCATGATGAAGATACTAATTGCTTTAGAATTAAGGAATACAAATAATGTGAGCTGCAGTTATAGGGATCAAAAAAGTTACAATGGGAATGTATTTGAGTGTTTATTATGTGATCAGTGCTAAGAAGTGTCATCATTTAATTTTACACTTAACAGTAATCCTGTGAGGATTATGCTATTATTAAATGCACTTGATACATTACAAAAAGGCTTATGGTTGATATAAATTGACCCAAGTAGAAGAGATCATGTTTTTATTCAGGTTTTCTGATTCTAGAGTTTGAGAGTTTGACCATCATTAGTGAGTAGTGACTATATTGTGTCTGAATTATTGACAGAATTTCTGATATTCATATGTACCAGGTTGTTTCTTAGAGTGGGAGCAGAGATGCAAGGGCTGCTAGTTCCGATGTGTAGGAGAAACTATCATTCATTTTGCATTTATCATTTTAAACGTTCTATATGTCTATCCTGGGCATGTGTTGAAGAACACAAGGAAGTATTAAATCACTCCTTCTTCTGAAGTTTGACTGGCAAAATTGGGCTAGAGTTACGAAATAAAATACAGGTTCCTAGTGAAATCTGAATTTCAGATACACAACCATAATTTATTGGAAATCCAAATTTAACTGGATATCTTCTATTATTCTCTGTTCTAGAACTCCACACTTCTAACATTTCTCATTCCTGTCTAAGCTCTTGTGTGTTTGGTTTTTGGCCATCGCTTTCACTGCTCTTTAAGCTCCCCCAGTAGAGTGGAGAGGTCTGTTTTCCCTCGTTTGGATTCCTACAGGCAGCGCAGGCCTGGCACAAGGTCATCACTAAGGAAGTGTTCACAGGGTGAAGGCGGTGGGTGCTGTTGAAGGAACCGGTAAAGCCTGTGGGATGAGAGAAGGAGCAGAGAGTGTTTTTGGGGTGGAGGCTCCCAGGAGGAGGCGGGACGGGCTGCGGTGCTGGGCGGATCCTCCTCCAGCTCCTGCTTGGAGGTCTCCAGAACAGGCTGGAGGCAGGGAGGGGGTCCCAAAAGCCTGGGGATGAGAAGGGGTTTTCCCGCATGGTCCCCCAGGCCCCCGTTCGCCTCAGGAAGACGGAGGATGAGCTCCTGGGCTGCTGGTGGTGGGCGTTGCGGGTGGGGCCGGTTAAGGTTCCCAGTGCCCGCACCCTGCCCAGGGAGCCCCGGATGGTGGCGTCGCTGTCAGTGTCTTCTCAGGAGGCTGCCCGTGTGACCGGATCCTTCGTGTCCCCACAGCACGTTTCTTGTGGCAGCTTAAGTTTGAATGTCATTTCTTCAATGGGACGGAGCGGGTGCGGTTGCTGGAAAGATGCATCTATAACCAAGAGGAGTCCGTGCGCTTCGACAGCGACGTGGGGGAGTACCGGGCGGTGACGGAGCTGGGGCGGCCTGATGCCGAGTACTGGAACAGCCAGAAGGACCTCCTGGAGCAGAGGCGGGCCGCGGTGGACACCTACTGCAGACACAACTACGGGGTTGGTGAGAGCTTCACAGTGCAGCGGCGAGGTGAGCGCGGCGCGGGGCGGGGCCTGAGTCCCTGTAAGCGGAGAATCTGAGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTAAGAAAGAGAGAGAGCGCGCCATCTGTGAGCATTTAGAATCCTCTCAATCCCCAGCAAGCAGTTCTGAGAGCACAGGTGTGTGTGTAGAGTGTGGATTTGTCTGGGTATGTCTGTTGTGGGAGGGGAGGCAGGAGGGGGCTGATTCTTATCCTTGGAGACCTCTGTGGGGAGGTGACAAGGGAGGTGGGTGCTGGGGGCTGGAGAGAGAGGAGACCTTGATTGTCTCGGGTCCTTAGAGATGCGGGGAAGGGAAATGTAAGGGGTGTGTGATTGGGGTGAAGGTTTAGGGGAGGACTGCTGAGGGGTAAGGAAGGTTTGGGATAATGTGAGGAGGCCGGTTCCAGACTCTCCCTGGCATACACCCTTCGTGTAATCTCTGAAATAAAAGTGTGTGCTGTTTGTTTGTAAAAGCATTAGATTAATTTCTAGAGGAACTGAGTAGACCTCTGAGGCACTCCTGAAGCTTCTTTATATCTAAATTTCTTGCTAGTTTTTTGGGTTTTTTTAGTGTGTATATTTTTACATAGTAGAAATGACTGTGAAACTAACTTTTTGAATTAAAGTTTTAACACAGTTACTATTTTATTATAATGCTAGTTTTCTAGTAGTTACATATTATTCTTTTATATATAATAGTTATGACACAACTCACCTCACTTTCCCCTTTGTTGACCTTTATTATGACATTCACCAAAAGTTGAAAATGTATGTTTCTGGTTAATTTTTAATTTATATTTTTTATTTGTAATTGCTTTGAATTATTTTGACCTATTTATTGGCGGATTATAATTATTGCTCTAAGAATTCCCTATTGTATTTGGTAGGCAATGGACAATGATCTATGGTCTGATATCTTGAGGGCTTAGTATTTTTCTCAGTGACTTTGTGGGTTCTTTGTGCTATAAGATTATTAACACTTTATTGATATTTGATCCAGCATTTGCTTCAGTTTGTGGTTTGTATGTGGATTTTGAAAGTTCTTTTCCATGTTAAGAATTTGAACTTTTTATTTAATAAAATATATTGCAAAATTTTTATTAATGATTTACAATCCATCTTAAATCTGCCATTTTGTGGCATTGTTGTCTCCAGGTTCCTCCTTACTTCTAAAAAAAATAGTTGTATTTATTGAGAGTATGCTAGTGTTGGGGATTTTCCTGGGCATAAGCACCCCAAGTAACAAGTCCCAGACACTGCCTTAATCCAAATGTGACTCTGGAAAGAAAAATCATTTTACAATGATAGGCCTAATAATAATTATGCTTGTGTTACACGGGAGATGCATTGATCAGCTAAATGTAAATATAAGAACTTTCAAAACTAAAATGACATTCCCTAATCCTTTTCTCTGCTTCGGGACTCATGCTTTTCTAGGAACGTAAAAATTTGGAGAATCATTTCTGTCTGTCCCACATTCCCAGGGGCAGAACAATTTCTGTTTTGTTCTAAGGTGTGAGTGCATGGCAGTAGTATTCCTAAAATTCATACTCGGTTTCCTCATGTACCCAATTCTGTCCCTTTATCTATGCATATTTCTTTAAATCATATTTTTCTGTCATGGGGTACAAGGATGATAAATAGGTGCCAAGTGGAGCACCCAAGTGTGATGAGCGCCCTCACAGTGGAATGGAGTGAGAAGCTTTCTGACCTTATAAACTGAAGGCTATCTTCAGTCATTGTTTTATATATTTTACATGCATTAATCCTCATATAACCCCAAGAGGTAAATTAGTATAATTATCCTTCATTGTAGGTGACAAAGTTGAGACACAGAAGAATCAAAAAACTCTTCCAGGATCAACCAGTAAAAGGCAGACCTTGGATTCGAACCAAGCAACCTGGCTCAAATATCAGTTTTAATTACTACACTCTATACTTTCCAAGATTTGTAAACAGTTTGACAATGCATGCCAATTTAAAGCTATGAAGAAACAAACACAATTTTTCACAACACCTCTCAAATCTAATGGGTCCTCACTGTCAAGATTAAATTCCAGGCTGATGACACTGTAAGGTCACATGGCCAGCTGTGCTATAGGCCTGGTCAAGGTCAGAGCCTGGGTTTGCAGAGAAGCAGACACACAGCCAAACCAGGAGACTTACTCTGTCTTCCTGACTCATTCTCTCTACATTTGTTTTCTCCTAGTTGAGCCTAAGGTGACTGTGTATCCTTCAAAGACCCAGCCCCTGCAGCACCACAACCTCCTGGTCTGCTCTGTGAGTGGTTTCTATCCAGGCAGCATTGAAGTCAGGTGGTTCCGGAACGGCCAGGAAGAGAAGGCTGGGGTGGTGTCCACAGGCCTGATCCAGAATGGAGATTGGACCTTCCAGACCCTGGTGATGCTGGAAACAGTTCCTCGGAGTGGAGAGGTTTACACCTGCCAAGTGGAGCACCCAAGTGTGACGAGCCCTCTCACAGTGGAATGGAGTGAGCAGCTTTCTGACTTCATAAATTTCTCACCCACCAAGAAGGGGACTGTGCTAATCCCTGAGTGTCAGGTTTCTCCTCTCCCACACCCTATTTTCATTTGCTCCATGTTCTCATCTCCATCAGCACAGGTCACTGGGGGTAGCCCTGTAGGTGTTTCTAGAAACACCTGTACCTCCTGGAGAAGCAGTCTCACCTGCCAGGCAGGAGAGACTGTCCCTCTTTTGAACCTCCCCATGATTTCGCAGGTCAGGGTCACCCACTCTCCCCAGGCTCCAGGCCCTGCTTCTGGGTCTGAGACTGAGTTTCTGGTGCTGTTGCTCTGAGTTATTTTTTGTGATCTGGGAAGAGGAGAAGTGTAGGGGCCTACCTGACATGAGGGGAATCCAATCTCAGCCCTGCCTTTTATTAGCTCTGTCACTCTAGACAAACTACTTAGCTTCATTGAGTCTCAGGCTTTCTGTTGATCAGATGTTGAACGCTTGCCTTACATCAAGGCTGTAATATTTGAATGAGTTTGATGTCTGAACATCGTAACTGTTCAGCGTGATTTGAAATCCTTTTTTTCTCCTGAAATGGCTAGTTATTTTAATTCTTGTGGGGCAGGCTTCTGCCCCATTTTCAAAGCTCTGAATCTTAGAGTCTCAATTAAAGAGGTTCAATTTGGAATAAGCATCACTAAACCTGGATTCCTCTCTCAGGAGCACGGTCTGAATCTGCACAGAGCAAGATGCTGAGTGGAGTCGGGGGCTTCGTGCTGGGCCTGCTCTTCCTTGGGGCCGGGCTGTTCATCTACTTCAGGAATCAGAAAGGTGAGGAGCCTTTGGGAGCTGACTCTCTCCATAGGCTTTTCTGGAGGAGGAACCATGGTTTTGCTGAGAGGTTAGTTCTCAGTATACGAGTGGCCCTGAATAAAGCCTTTCTTTCCCCAAACGGCTCTAATGTCCTGCTAATCCAGAAATCATCAGTGCATGGTTACTATGTCAAAGCATAATAGCTTGTGGCCTGCAGAGACAAGAGGAAGGTTAACAAGTAGGGGTCCTTTTGTTTGAGATCCTGGAGCAAATTAAGGAAGAGCCACTAAGGCTAATGGAATTACACTGGATCCTGTGACAGACACTTCAGGCTTCATGGGTCACATGGTCTGTCTCTGCTCCTTTCTGCCCCTTTCTGCCCTGGTTGGTGCGGGTTGTGGTGTTAGAGAAATCTCAGGTGGGAGATCTGCGGCTGGGACATTGTGTTGGAGGACAGATTTGCTTCAATAACTTTTAAGTGTATTTCTTTTCCTCTTTTTCCCAGGACACTCTGGACTTCAGCCAACAGGTAATACCTTTTAATCCTCTTTTAGAAACAGACACAGTTTCCCTAGTGAGAGGTGAAGCCAGCTGGACTTCTGGGTGGGGTGGGGACTTGGAGAACTTTTCTTACAAGAGGTTTCTAAATGCCCCAATCAGTGCTTTGTAAAAACACACCAATAGGTTCTCTGTGGCTAGCTGGATGTTTGTAAAATGGACCAATTTGCACTCTGTAAAATGGACCAATCAGCATTCTTTAAAATGGACCAATCAGCACTTTTAAAATGGGCCAATCAGCACTCTTTAAAATGGACCAATCAGCACTCTTTAAAATGGACCAATCTGCAGGACATGGGCAGGGACAAATACAGGAATAAAAGCTGGCCACCCCAACCAGCAGTGGCAACCCACTCAGGTCCTCTTCCCTGCTGTGGAAGTTTTGTTCTTTTGATCTTCACAATAAATCTTGCTGCTGCCTACTCTTTGGGTCCCTGCCGCCTTTAAGAGCTGTAACACTCACTGTGAAGGTCTGCTTGAAGTCAGCGAGACCACAAACCCACTGGAAGGAACAAACTGCGGACACACTAGAATGATGGTAGAGGTGATAAGGCATGAGACAGAAATAATAGGAAAGACTTTGGATCCAAATTTCTGATCAGGCAATTTACACCAAAATTCCTCCTCTCCACTTAGAAAAGGGCTGTGCTCTGCGGGACTATTGGCTCAGGGGAGACTCAGGAACTTGTTTTTCTGCTTCCTGCAGTGCTCTCATCTGAGCCCTTGAAAGAGGAGAAAAGAAACTGTTAGTAGAGCCAGGTTGAAAACAACACTCTCCTCTGTCTTTTGCAGGATTCCTGAGCTGAAATGCAGATGACCACATTCAAGGAAGAACCTTCTGTCCCAGCTTTGCAGGA"

aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
aligner.match_score = 2
aligner.mismatch_score = -3
aligner.open_gap_score = -5
aligner.extend_gap_score = -2
aligner.query_right_open_gap_score = 0
aligner.query_left_open_gap_score = 0
aligner.query_right_extend_gap_score = 0
aligner.query_left_extend_gap_score = 0
alignments = aligner.align(ref_seq, query_seq)  # <= this is where the MemoryError occurs

for a in sorted(alignments):
    print(a)
```

This is Python 3 on Windows 10. The Biopython version is 1.72.

Edit: and here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/foo/temp.py", line 15, in <module>
    alignments = aligner.align(ref_seq, query_seq)  # <= this is where the MemoryError occurs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36\lib\site-packages\Bio\Align\__init__.py", line 1352, in align
    score, paths = _aligners.PairwiseAligner.align(self, seqA, seqB)
MemoryError: Out of memory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, where the `aligner.align()` call led to the `MemoryError`, it was likely due to a memory leak in an earlier Biopython version (since the core code is written in C, not python). This has been fixed in the later Biopython versions, so the solution is to upgrade Biopython to the latest version (now 1.77).

---

In other cases, `sorted(alignments)` could be the cause. You create, in memory, a list of all the alignments, which can be massive. You can check the size of this potential list in advance by calling `print(len(alignments))`.

Since `alignments` is a *lazy* iterator, you just iterate over the alignments 1 by 1 `for a in alignments:`, solving your memory issue, but I would still not recommend printing them all. Maybe you just want the first alignment `first_alignment = next(alignments)` or the first say `10` alignments:

```
import itertools

for a in itertools.islice(alignments, 10):
    print(a)
```

Comment: Nope, the "Out of memory" error already occurs on the "align" call. I have updated the MCVE to clarify this.
(Since the sequences are very close to each other, I don't expect a large number of alignments, actually. I only want the highest scoring one, anyway.)

Comment: @CodingCat How long are your input sequences? Did you profile your memory use? How much memory is it actually using? And how many alignments were generated when you check `len()`?

Comment: The input sequences are in the MCVE (11101 bp and 10413 bp). How do I go about profiling the memory use?

Comment: @CodingCat Oh you get a memory error with those actual sequences? (I assumed they were longer and this was just an example). can you show the full traceback? and what is your version `print(Bio.__version__)`?

Comment: Yes, those are the actual sequences, which is why I was surprised by the MemoryError. I have added the Traceback and Biopython version (1.72) to the question.

Comment: @CodingCat I don't get an error with the latest Biopython version, possibly memory leak fixed, try upgrading

Comment: O_O That fixed it. I feel stupid now. Thanks! Want to incorporate that into your answer so I can accept it?